# NameError: name 'glPushMatrix' is not defined

Tags: python, opengl, render

Try to run a test code for stable baselines gym

```
import gym

from stable_baselines3 import A2C

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")

model = A2C("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10_000)

obs = env.reset()
for i in range(100):
    action, _state = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
    if done:
      obs = env.reset()
```

found the error "NameError: name 'glPushMatrix' is not defined"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cart_pole.py", line 14, in <module>
    env.render()
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 295, in render
    return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 229, in render
    return self.viewer.render(return_rgb_array=mode == "rgb_array")
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 126, in render
    self.transform.enable()
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 232, in enable
    glPushMatrix()
NameError: name 'glPushMatrix' is not defined
```

I  tried  "pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate", which didn't help
also uninstall pyglet and install again , did't work too
Any Idea???

Comment: Which version of gym are you using? I think that if you install the latest one 0.26.2 the error will disappear, but your code will not be working with the latest gym. So pfaya has the right solution if you want the quickest way to get this fixed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just had the same problem. Fixed it by installing an older version of pyglet:

```
$ pip install pyglet==1.5.27
```

I don't know if this is the latest version that avoids the problem, but it works.

Comment: This is the answer to this problem. ✅

Comment: I confirm that 1.5.27 is the latest version of pyglet which avoids the problem. See https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/migration.html "pyglet 2.0 includes a number of breaking changes". And see https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/releases that 1.5.27 is the version immediately preceding 2.0.0. And I tried downgrading to 2.0, same error; when downgrading to 1.5.27, worked perfectly